# Sci-fi novel with a house used by aliens as a station when space travelling, protected by a force field

Tags: story-identification, novel

Sci-fi novel I read as a kid, with a house and a caretaker. The house was used by alien races as a station when travelling through space. The house looked normal from a distance but could not be entered because of some invisible force field. The man was chosen by the aliens as a caretaker of this house.

Comment: Welcome! Can you remember anything else? I'm sorry to ask because I'm sure you put down everything that came to mind, but questions which don't have much to go on often get closed sadly, so is there anything else you can think of? Things you may not even think are things. How long ago did you read it, when were you a kid? Was it likely intended as a children's book? Anything at all really, the more the better

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you thinking of *Way Station* (1963), by Clifford Simak?

> Enoch Wallace, an American Civil War veteran, is chosen by an alien called Ulysses to administer a way station for interplanetary travel. Travelers arrive by a form of teleportation by duplication, where the original body remains at the source and a new live copy is created at the destination. Enoch's job is to monitor the machinery of the way station and make sure arrival conditions meet the biological needs of the wide variety of aliens. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Way_Station_(novel)))

Comment: Yes! That's the one I've been looking for for so long! Thank you so much rojomoke!

Comment: You're very welcome